# How to show $P_U $ is linear for the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U, W$ are subspaces such that $V=U\bigoplus W$. Then we know $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as $v=u+w$ for $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Define the function $P_U:V\to V$ by $P_U (v)=P_U (u+w)=u$.

How to show $P_U $  is linear for the following condition?

My try:

$P_U (x+y)=P_U (u_1+u_2+w_2+w_2)=u_1+u_2=($something here I don't know$)=P_U (x)+P_U (y)$

$P_U (ax)=au=$something here I don't know$=aP_U (x)$.

Someone have any suggestion? In addition, how to show that Ker$(P_U)=W,$ Im$(P_U)=U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close for the first part. One approach to solving problems of this form is to work forwards and backwards until you meet in the middle. You worked the "forwards" part perfectly. Working backwards,
$P_U(x) + P_U(y) = P_U(u_1 + w_1) + P_U(u_2+w_2) = u_1 + u_2$. You have arrived at the same expression where you ended the forwards part. Now you glue both parts together reversing the order of the part you did backwards like below:

If $x=u_1 + w_1$ and $y=u_2 + w_2$ where $u_i \in U$ and $w_i \in W$ then
\begin{align*}
P_U(x+y) & = P_U(u_1 + w_1 + u_2 + w_2) \\
         & = P_U( (u_1 + u_2) + (w_1 + w_2)) \\
         & = u_1 + u_2 \\
         & = P(u_1 + w_1) + P(u_2 + w_2) \\
         & = P(x) + P(y)
\end{align*}

For the second part, 
\begin{align*}
P_U(ax) &= P_U(au_1 + aw_1) \\
        &= au_1 \\
        &= aP_U(u_1 + w_1) \\
        &= aP_U(x)
\end{align*}

To show the $Ker(T)=W$ and $Im(T)=U$ you could start out by writing the definition of $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$. Then one standard approach to prove that two sets are equal is to show that $Ker(T) \subset W$ and $W \subset Ker(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y \in V$.  Then we may write $x=u_1+w_1$ and $y=u_2+w_2$ for some $u_1, u_2 \in U$ and $w_1, w_2 \in W$.

Then $x+y=(u_1+w_1)+(u_2+w_2)=(u_1+u_2)+(w_1+w_2)$, so that $P_U(x+y)=P((u_1+u_2)+(w_1+w_2))=u_1+u_2$.  On the other hand, $P_U(x)=P_U(u_1+w_1)=u_1$ and $P_U(y)=P_U(u_2+w_2)=u_2$. From this, we see that $P_U(x)+P_U(y)=u_1+u_2=P_U(x+y)$.

Similarly, since $ax=a(u_1+w_1)=au_1+aw_1$, we have $P_U(ax)=P_U(au_1+aw_1)=au_1$ and $aP_U(x)=aP_U(u_1+w_1)=au_1$, so $P_U(ax)=aP_U(x)$.

$Ker(P_U)$ is the set of all elements sent to zero under your map $P_U$. For an element $x=u+w\in V$, $P_U(x)=u=0$ iff $u=0$. So the kernel is just all elements $x$ in $V$ of the form $x=w$, which is exactly your set $W$.

$Im(P_U)$ is the set of all possible outputs of $P_U$. Since $P_U(x)=u$ for $u\in U$, the set of outputs is exactly $U$.

If the Kernel and Image parts are not clear, you could try a common technique for showing two sets are equal: $A=B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. So try taking an element of $Ker(P_U)$ and showing it's in $W$; then take an element of $W$ and show it's in $Ker(P_U)$.  Similarly for the image.

I hope this helps!